# C++ memory: deleting an unused array of bool can change the result from right to wrong

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging, memory

I am trying to solve Project Euler [Problem 88](https://projecteuler.net/problem=88), and I did it without too much effort; however, I find that some seemingly irrelevant code in my program is affecting the result. Here's my complete code (it's not short, but I cannot locate the error. I believe it would be obvious to more experienced eyes, so please read my description first):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

bool m[24001][12001];
bool p[24001]; // <------------ deleting this line will cause error in result!
long long answer[12001];

int main() {
  long long i;
  long long j;
  long long l;
  set<long long> all;
  long long s = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= 24000; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= 12000; j++) {
      m[i][j] = false;
    }
  }
  m[1][1] = true;
  for (i = 2; i <= 24000; i++) {
    m[i][1] = true;
    for (j = 2; (j <= i) && (i * j <=24000); j++) {
      for (l = 1; l <= i; l++) {
    if (m[i][l]) {
      m[i * j][l + 1 + (i * j) - i - j] = true;
    }
      }
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i <= 24000; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= 12000; j++) {
      if (m[i][j] && (answer[j] == 0)) {
    answer[j] = i;
      }
    }
  }
  for (i = 2; i <= 12000; i++) {
    cout << answer[i] << endl;
    all.insert(answer[i]);
  }
  cout << all.size() << endl;
  for (set<long long>::iterator it = all.begin(); it != all.end(); it++) {
    //cout << *it << endl;
    s += *it;
  }
  cout << s << endl;
}
```

With the "useless" bool array, all the answers are right, between 0 and 24000; but without it, some answers in the middle got corrupted and become very large numbers.

I am completely confused now; why would that unused array affect the middle of the answer array?

Thanks and sorry for the long code! I will be grateful if someone could edit the code into a better example, I simply son't know what is with the code.

Comment: `m[i * j][l + 1 + (i * j) - i - j] = true;` o_O  What does this program do?  You need to rework your logic so that it is clearer and simpler, with named objects instead of these crazy expressions explaining what the result means.  The program almost certainly yields the wrong result because you are overrunning the end of `m` and writing into the memory occupied by `answer`; find out where your math is wrong and you'll find the bug.

Comment: Is it intentional that your arrays are one longer than what you are all +1 and why are you iterating in such a strange way?

Comment: You are definitely writing beyond the bounds of the array `m` somewhere, when the unused array `p` exists, `m` overwrites in to its contents which doesnt affect the `answer` array but once `p` is removed the overwriting happens in to `answer` array showing up the problems.

Comment: Check the bounds of **ALL** array accesses. Come back when you've found the problem.

Comment: @Als: please change that to an answer; I believe it is the reason, and the line that caused it is the line James pointed out.

Comment: @Als: Also, could you explain it more? Why would it got affected **in the middle**? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, adding this to an answer.

You are definitely writing beyond the bounds of the array `m` somewhere, when the unused array `p` exists, `m` overwrites in to its contents which doesn't affect the answer array but once `p` is removed the overwriting happens in to answer array showing up the problems.

Overwriting beyond the bounds of the array is an **Undefined Behavior** and it causes your program to be ill-formed. With Undefined Behavior all safe bets are off and any behavior is possible. While your program may work sometimes or crash sometimes or give incorrect results.Practically, Anything is possible and the behavior may or even may not be explainable.

Comment: Thanks! (Teeth-grinding) I must prohibit myself from using Java for the next a couple of months; I am too spoiled by nice exceptions in Java.

Answer (score 3):

You do a silly thing in here:

```
      m[i * j][l + 1 + (i * j) - i - j] = true;
```

Say, i=160, j=150, l=1... You will try to access m[24000][23692]... And you corrupt the stack, so behavior is undefined.

Next time try to use some profiler and/or debugger.

Comment: It doesn't corrupt the stack though, because it writes to the array below. Valgrind reports no errors with this program.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst valgrind's memory checker only works with stack allocated memory. Although there is another tool which seems to cope with the stack to some extend. It is easy to track the problems though: just replace the use of the subscript operator with uses of `at()` and the arrays with `std::vector<bool>`

Answer (score 3):

Add:

`#include <cassert>`

at the begining and

```
assert( (i * j) * 12001 + (l + 1 + (i * j) - i - j) <= 12001*24001 );
```

before the following line:

```
m[i * j][l + 1 + (i * j) - i - j] = true;
```

The assertion will fail, which means you write outside the bounds of the array `m`.

Answer (score 1):

In one of your nested loops you use `l` as the index for the second dimension. This variable can run from `0` to `i` and `i`, in turn, can run from `0` to `24000`. Since your second dimension of the array can only be index from `0` to `12000` this causes a classic out of range error. This also nicely explains why adding an extra array avoid the problem: the out of range accesses go to the "unused" array rather than overwriting the result.

Comment: If you look closer, it's not that simple, since `i * j` cannot go past  24000, and `j` starts at 2. Nevertheless, as pointed out by Vlad, there is an out-of-bound access there.

Comment: @Cameron: actually, Vlad points at exactly the same line of code for exactly the same reason as I do - except that I described the situation instead of quoting the code...